# Ameritrade price close difference

Tags: price, real-time-quotes

Using the Ameritrade app, the close price ( market is closed ) shows a close price of $5.26.
The actual close price is $5.78 in other apps and a simple web search.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the data that you are looking at is for the close of regular trading hours.  Some data providers will also include after hours quotes and they are usually different.

FWIW, I have two brokerage accounts open in real time and occasionally I see that Ameritrade takes a second or two to update and catch up to my primary account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In Ameritrade, RRR is shown as: 5.26  (39.89%)
Bid Ask
5.40 5.69 -- A search will show the close @ $5.78 with after hours @ $5.76 - this is long after the close. If you attempt a trade, the ask is below the actual price?

Comment: it appears the $5.26 price was not the close. The $5.26 is the after hours current price. It may have been Ameritrade was able to show an accurate current price while everyone else was delayed. Thanks Bob

Comment: It's early Friday AM and Ameritrade is showing a close of $5.78 which aligns with your quote.  However, I can't sort the discrepancies out because we're looking at quotes at different times.  In general, at 4 PM EST, quotes widen as traders pull their orders (unless there's news and a reason to trade).  Then you have after hours quotes (and possible trading) that shows another set of data. And then you have some sources that cite regular hours whereas others include after hours.  I'd suggest that you check and compare the various sites in real time.